# "Listen to his parents argue" vs. "listen to his parents arguing."

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Example sentence:

> Now and then he'd press his ear against the door and listen to his parents **argue/arguing** in the hallway.

Do the two options have the same meaning? Or they mean slightly different things?

Comment: _Arguing_ is correct. They were arguing while he was listening.

Comment: Your comment set me thinking: How about? **Listen to her sing / watch him bat / see them rejoice**. Would you regard these as legitimate options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Listen to them arguing.*

Here, you denote continuity of action, through the usage of the **participial phrase** "arguing", which is a **present participle** (and *not* gerund). So you just highlight the fact that some *two people are arguing and you want the addressed person to listen to the same.* Nothing special.

> *Listen to them argue.*

Here, you are **exemplifying their act of arguing**. You choose to use the **verb** "argue" in the **present indefinite tense**, which says nothing about whether the argument is going on or not in the present. But there is subtle indication in this sentence that you **want the listener to listen to the argument no matter in which indefinite period it occurs.** It's as if you are exemplifying the act of argument between two people. Like:

> Listen to his parents argue. No cursing, no accusations, no guilt tripping. They talk and solve actual problems like adults.

So I think there's a subtle difference in meaning.